# How can I take the values that are made inside the iterations of the for loop and use them outside of it but in the same method?

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to be able to take the values out of the for loop as well as make individual values for the separate iterations of the for loop so that I can put them into the comparison if/else statements below the for loop.

```
public static void calculateBirthdays(Scanner console) {
        //Print purpose
        System.out.println("This program compares two birthdays");
        System.out.println("and displays which one is sooner.");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int todayYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int todayMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int todayDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat();

        int todayDayValue = absDayVal(todayMonth, todayDay, todayYear);

        System.out.println("Today is " + d.format(cal.getTime()) + ", day #" + todayDayValue + " of the year.");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Person " + i + ":\nWhat month, day and year were you born?");

            int month = console.nextInt();
            int day = console.nextInt();
            int year = console.nextInt();

            int daysPassed = absDayVal(month, day, year);
            int daysInYear = leapYear(todayYear);

            int daysUntilBday = daysAway(daysPassed, todayDayValue, daysInYear);

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

            System.out.println(month + "/" + day + "/" + todayYear + " falls on day #" + todayDayValue + " of " + daysInYear + ".");

            if(todayDayValue == daysPassed){
                System.out.println("Happy birthday!");
            } else if (todayDayValue != daysPassed){
                System.out.println("Your next birthday is in " + daysUntilBday + " day(s).");
                System.out.println("That is " + df.format((percentUntil(daysUntilBday, daysInYear)) * 100) + " percent of a year away.");
            }
        }

        if(percent < percent) {
            System.out.println("Person 1's birthday is sooner.");
        } else if (percent < percent) {
            System.out.println("Person 2's birthday is sooner.");
        } else if (percent == percent) {
            System.out.println("Wow, you share the same birthday!");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Declare them outside of the loop, assign values inside of it.

Comment: Just a side note, your method `calculateBirthdays` does _way_ more than calculate birthdays and should really be split up into separate methods.  You would not expect something named `calculateBirthdays` to use a `Scanner` as a parameter either, I would think it would take in two birthdays as two parameters or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare them outside of the loop like this.

```
int month;
int day;
int year;

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    System.out.println("Person " + i + ":\nWhat month, day and year were you born?");

    month = console.nextInt();
    day = console.nextInt();
    year = console.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

This concept is known as **scope**. [Here is an article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) that might give you a better understanding on variable scope.